# Can't get Connection State on page load with my phonegap jquery app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load a data feed when my phonegap app loads.  It works fine, except that when I don't have a data connection, I want the system to sense this and then give a nice message like, "Sorry you don't have a data connection.".   Once the page is all loaded I can click a button and run a function that tells me my connection state.  However, it simply won't run this code automatically when the page loads, and I can't figure out why.  I have the same problem when I test this on iOS or Android.  I've stripped out only the basics, so hopefully someone can't discover the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jsonp-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
<script>
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    if(states[networkState] == 'No network connection') { show_no_connection(); }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkConnection();
});

function show_no_connection() {
        $('#status').html('You Have No Data Connection!');  
}   


</script>       

</head>
<body>

 <div id="status">SO FAR, YOU HAVE A CONNECTION.</div>
     <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='checkConnection();'>Check your connection</a><br/><br/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>       
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic **`jQuery`** syntax **`$(document).ready(function(){`** should not be used with **`jQuery Mobile`**, it will not work correctly not to mention it can't be used to initialize **`Phonegap`** code. More about this topic can be found in this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

This should be used to solve this problem:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    if(states[networkState] == 'No network connection') { show_no_connection();
}

function show_no_connection() {
    $('#status').html('You Have No Data Connection!');  
}
```

Code needs to wait for **`Phonegap`** framework initialization and it is done like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```